# Brightcove autoplay videos not playing in iPad Safari

Tags: video.js, brightcove, zencoder

We have integrated Brightcove videos in our application. Autoplay videos play in desktop browsers but not playing in ipad Safari browser.
Please suggest if there is any limitation of playing autoplay videos in iPad/iPhone Safari browsers.

Please let me know if further info needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autoplay option is disabled by default on mobile devices to avoid bandwidth consumption. User has to click play button to autoplay the video.

However if you want to enforce autoplay and muted attributes, but it will work only on latests versions of Chrome for Android and iOS 10.

You can read more about it here:

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay
- https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/